# Word in a phone call

Tags: word, wordplay, no-computers

This is a 6 letter word

123456 these numbers represent the letters in the word.

Here is the short phone conversation betweeen 2 friends

-*Hello*

-Hi 346

-*Hey 2356, where are you?*

-123456, Europe!

-*How do you like it?*

-It is 356, 234. The place, but not the 3456

-*256?*

-yeah, not 23456. Lot of 24136s

-*What next?*

-Got to go, 253 may be!

-*Enjoy!*

PLEASE NO CHECKING INTERNET.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you requesting that we not look for *this exact puzzle* on the internet (in which case it would be interesting to know where it comes from), or that we not use the internet to look up e.g. lists of countries? If the latter, should we also assume e.g. PLEASE NO CHECKING ATLASES?

Comment: I assume they just want us not using some sort of program to just cycle through the letter sets and come up with the city name... if we can't look up city names this requires an extensive knowledge since there are thousands of possible 6 letter cities.

Comment: There's no guarantee it's a city name, either. Might be a country. Might be a word ("Holiday, Europe!" "Sightseeing, Europe!" "Boating, Europe!", etc.). Anyway, I'd rather know exactly what it is Deepak doesn't want us doing...

Comment: Oh fair point.. Although none of those fit 123456 ;) but yeah what is wanted would help

Comment: If I had something that actually fitted the letters I'd be posting an answer rather than a comment. I don't think Deepak should be telling us whether the word is a country name, city name, activity, etc.; that's for us to figure out.

Comment: It is no fun if you search the internet for 6 letter words or program to get it. That is all. Just my 2 cents

Comment: It is a 6 letter word.

Comment: (I hope some of them are not names), Does the comma in 356,234 mean two 3-lettered words or a single 6-lettered word?

Comment: Sid, two seperate 3 letter words

Comment: Also very much American language, Slangs too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The word is:

> **ABROAD**

The complete conversation is:

> — Hello!
>  — Hi **ROD**!
>  — Hey **BRAD**, where are you?
>  — **ABROAD**, Europe!
>  — How do you like it?
>  — It is **RAD**, **BRO**. The place, but not the **ROAD**.
>  — **BAD**?
>  — yeah, not **BROAD**. Lot of **BOARD**s.
>  — What next?
>  — Got to go, **BAR** may be!

How did I find it?

> By trying several things. I got a good start when trying places to go for the last word. **PUB** didn't work, but **BAR** did. Then I got **BRO** and the rest fell in place.

Comment: EXCELLENT M Oehm. Good Logic